# Where can I watch Black Butler?

Tags: black-butler

I want to watch Black Butler, but Crunchyroll won't let me.
Is there another site where I can watch it? I tried Crunchyroll and Youtube, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 1):

[Funimation|now](https://www.funimation.com/shows/black-butler/) has 2 seasons of *Black Butler*.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch it on places such as Netflix, etc.

Comment: All though Netflix may have this series, Netflix also limits series to specific regions. Could you include the regions where this series is available on netflix?